# Control directive is not allowed in .aspx file

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to follow the  [Microsoft instructions on how to create a user control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw(v=vs.140).aspx)

my aim is to convert the .aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Customize the queue UI" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="CuteWebUI" Namespace="CuteWebUI" Assembly="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <CuteWebUI:Uploader ID="uploader1" runat="server">
        </CuteWebUI:Uploader>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following

```
<%@ Control CodeBehind="kgfileUploader.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleUserControl" Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CuteWebUI" Namespace="CuteWebUI" Assembly="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc00d4b0e43ec38d" %>

<h3> <u>User Control</u> </h3>

<CuteWebUI:Uploader ID="uploader1" runat="server">
</CuteWebUI:Uploader>
```

But I get an error "Control directive is not allowed in .aspx file"

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Does this page help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x6sx01c.aspx. Did you rename it with the .ascx suffix?

Comment: Ah I missed the rename to .ascx  Thank you. Please write it as the answer.